# How to write a macro that automatically detects an incoming bot check in-game and clicks the correct answer?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract, game-automation

While playing the game, a bot control appears at certain intervals as follows.

[image: regions created]
[image: regions created 2]

I created 5 different regions using the OpenCV and Python-tesseract libraries in Python. It scans the mathematical operation or text written in yellow in the main region and prints it to the console. I got this part done. But it doesn't see numbers or texts in 4 different regions found for answers.

I also tried to find it with different color settings, but I didn't succeed. I tried scanning the color codes in different ways.
I tried to find the Regions by editing them.

My aim is to understand the question correctly in the verification processes that I come across in this way, then to click on the part with the correct answer with the mouse.

What do you suggest?
Below is my code sample.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import pyautogui
import numpy as np
import re

def find_text_in_region(region, color_range):
    # Ekran görüntüsünü alın
    screen = pyautogui.screenshot()
    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screen), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    # Bölgeyi sınırlayıcı dikdörtgeni çizin
    x, y, w, h = region
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Bölgedeki metni alın
    region_image = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    region_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(region_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_color = np.array([color_range[0], 100, 100])
    upper_color = np.array([color_range[1], 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(region_hsv, lower_color, upper_color)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(mask)

    return text

def process_math_expression(expression):
    # İfadedeki boşlukları kaldırın
    expression = expression.replace(" ", "")

    try:
        result = eval(expression)
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print("Matematiksel ifade hesaplanamadı:", expression)
        print("Hata:", str(e))
        return None

def search_answers_in_regions(regions):
    answers = []

    for region_index, region in enumerate(regions, start=1):
        # Ekran görüntüsünü alın
        screen = pyautogui.screenshot()
        image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screen), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        # Bölgeyi sınırlayıcı dikdörtgeni çizin
        x, y, w, h = region
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # Bölgedeki metni alın
        region_image = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        region_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(region_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        lower_color = np.array([20, 100, 100])
        upper_color = np.array([30, 255, 255])
        mask = cv2.inRange(region_hsv, lower_color, upper_color)
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(mask)

        # Metni konsola yazdır
        print(f"Region {region_index} metni: {text}")

        # Metni cevaplar listesine ekleyin
        answers.append(text)

    return answers

def main():
    # Ana bölge ve cevap bölgelerini tanımlayın
    main_region = (1007, 473, 150, 40)
    answer_regions = [
        (957, 511, 246, 18),  # Region 1
        (957, 543, 246, 18),  # Region 2
        (957, 575, 246, 18),  # Region 3
        (957, 607, 246, 18)   # Region 4
    ]

    # Ana bölgedeki matematik ifadesini veya metni bulun
    text = find_text_in_region(main_region, (20, 30))
    print("Matematiksel ifade veya metin:", text)

    # Matematik ifadesini hesaplayın
    result = process_math_expression(text)

    if result is not None:
        print("Sonuç:", result)

    # Cevap bölgelerindeki metinleri veya sayıları bulun
    answers = search_answers_in_regions(answer_regions)

    # Cevapları konsola yazdırın
    for region_index, answer in enumerate(answers, start=1):
        print(f"Cevap Region {region_index}: {answer}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: İ still  waiting